# Reading CSV file using structs, error trace trap

Tags: c

I am trying to pull strings from a csv file that has quotations

Example line:

```
"2015","Canada (excluding territories)","","35 to 49 years","Males","Diabetes","Percent","Percent","239","units","0","v110789429","1.4.2.10.4","4.9","","","","1")
```

but this code keeps returning a error `zsh: trace trap`. I dont understand why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_RECORDS 211

typedef struct question1 //name of struct
{
    int ref_date; //year;
    char geo[25]; //country/province
    char age_group[50]; //the age group
    char sex[10];  //gender
    double value; //% of pop. that has diabetes
} question1;

int main() {

    FILE *file; //open file

    file = fopen("dummy.csv", "r"); //open file;

    // if file doesnt open
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("error");
        return 1;
    }

    question1 arr[MAX_RECORDS];
    int columns = 18;
    int records = 0;

    int initalize = 0;

    int ref_date_num = 0;
    int geo_num = 1;
    int age_num = 3;
    int sex_num = 4;
    int value_num = 12;
    char buf[4096];

    fscanf(file, "%s", buf);

    while (fgetc(file) != EOF && records < MAX_RECORDS) {
        char buf[4096];

        question1 temp;

        fscanf(file, "%s", buf);

        int charPointer = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {

            if (i > value_num) {
                break;
            }

            char item[100] = "";
            int itemPointer = 0;
            // loop through all columns until equal to "," signifying end of column
            // value at current column put into item
            // item = "2015"

            while (strtok(buf, ",")) {
                item[itemPointer] = buf[charPointer];
                charPointer++;
                itemPointer++;
            }

            printf("%s\n", item);

            // points to start of next column
            charPointer++;

            // item = "2015"

            char rawItem[100] = "";
            int rawItemPointer = 0;

            // looping though item not including quotation marks
            for (int j = 1; j < itemPointer - 1; j++) {

                rawItem[rawItemPointer] = item[j];
                rawItemPointer++;
            }

            // rawItem = 2015

            if (i == ref_date_num) {
                sscanf(rawItem, "%d", &temp.ref_date);
            }
            else if (i == geo_num) {
                strcpy(temp.geo, rawItem);
            }
            else if (i == age_num) {
                strcpy(temp.age_group, rawItem);
            }
            else if (i == sex_num) {
                strcpy(temp.sex, rawItem);
            }
            else if (i == value_num) {
                sscanf(rawItem, "%lf", &temp.value);
            }
        }

        arr[records] = temp;
        records++;
    }

    fclose(file);

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Compiling with `-fsanitize=address` can be very useful to debug such problems quickly.

Comment: ... It shows that `item[itemPointer] = buf[charPointer];` results in a buffer overflow.

Comment: Your `strtok` loop makes no sense, and it's the root cause of your problem.

Comment: Next time please indent your code properly so it is readable. Readable code is important for us, but it's even more important for you.

Comment: Answered this yesterday for another: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75808262/17592432