# c - creating program to remove empty lines and quotations from file

Tags: c, string, file

I am working on a program, or a piece of a program, that removes empty lines at the end of a .csv file, as well as any quotation marks in the file, and creates a new text file. See my code below.

```
FILE *dr;   //dirty file, with blank lines and quotations
dr = fopen ("file.csv","r");

FILE *cl;   //clean file, with no blank lines or quotations
cl = fopen ("clean_file.txt", "w");

char c_row1 [CHAR]; //string containing line before cleaning
char c_row2 [CHAR]; //string containing line after cleaning
int new;    //index of new string where non-quotation character will be placed
for (int r = 0; r < 211; r ++)  //for each column (I know the number of lines in the .csv file)
{
    new = 0;    //initialize index at zero
    fgets (c_row1, CHAR, dr);   //get line in original file, place it in string
    
    for (int c = 0; c_row1 [c] != '\n'; c ++)   //loop which iterates through each character in the dirty string, stopping at the end of the line
    {
        if (c_row1 [c] != '"')
        {
            c_row2 [new] = c_row1 [c];  //place non-quotation character at index of new string
            new ++; //iterate index if character is placed
        }
        c_row2 [new] = '\n';    //add missing new line character end of each line
    }
    
    fputs (c_row2, cl); //place new clean line in text file
        
}
```

Rather than neatly placing each new line in the new file, it messily places each value in the file. There is some order to it, but at some points it is unorganized and not what I expect.

Comment: One problem is the absence of code that terminates `c_row2` with `'\0'`. Without that, it's not a C string. Another problem is stripping double quote from a CSV without regard for whether or not they're there to "embed" a comma in a string (ie: not a field separator) OR there to 'escape' a literal double quote in a field...  Have a look at this answer from yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75808262/17592432

Comment: You should always check that `fopen()` — or any other file opening function — succeeded.  Things can go wrong even when you don't expect them to; in fact, that's when they most often go wrong.  Using a fixed count for the number of lines to read is not sensible.  You should use `while (fgets(c_row1, sizeof(c_row1), dr) != NULL)` instead of the `for` loop.  This also checks that `fgets()` works — your current code doesn't know if the file ends early.

Comment: Style guide: array subscripts bind very tightly and, in idiomatic C, should not be separated from the array name by a space.  Similar comments apply to the structure member access operators, dot `.` and arrow `->`; there should not be spaces around them, either.

Comment: `fgets (c_row1, CHAR, dr);  for (int c = 0; c_row1 [c] != '\n'; c ++)`is very bad if the line read did not fully fit in `c_row`.  The next loop  leads to UB as it lacks a `'\n'`.

Answer (score 0):

modify the body of main loop as follows:

1. always use construction `c_row2[new++] = next_char`
2. add new line out of inner loop
3. add EOS to the final string

====

```
fgets (c_row1, CHAR, dr);    
for (int c = 0; c < CHAR && c_row1 [c] != '\n'; c ++)
{
    if (c_row1[c] == '"') continue; // skipp this char
    c_row2[new++] = c_row1 [c];  // copy other chars
}
if (new == 0) continue; // empty line
c_row2[new++] = '\n';   // add new line char
c_row2[new++] = 0;      // add EOS char
fputs (c_row2, cl);     // output cleared line
```